# Real vs. Integer in Fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77, g77

I have a program which loops over one variable and computes a value at each step:

```
  program cpout

  implicit none

  !declarations
    integer, parameter :: dp = selected_real_kind(15)
                ! kind value for double precision

    real(dp), parameter :: Ru = 8.314472_dp    
    real(dp) :: cp
    integer :: loT, hiT, i
    real(dp) :: iT
    real(dp),dimension(14) :: ic8a
    real(dp) :: ic8t
    real(dp) :: ic8c

    loT = 300
    hiT = 3000

! ic8a is populated using a subroutine call
! I have checked, it reads in reals as it is supposed to

    do i = loT, hiT, 1

      iT = real(i,dp)

      if (iT > ic8t) then
        ic8c = Ru*(ic8a(1) + ic8a(2)*iT + ic8a(3)*(iT**2)
 *                 + ic8a(4)*(iT**3) + ic8a(5)*(iT**4))
      else
        ic8c = Ru*(ic8a(8) + ic8a(9)*iT + ic8a(10)*(iT**2)
 *                 + ic8a(11)*(iT**3) + ic8a(12)*(iT**4))
      end if

    end do

  end program cpout
```

In my first attempt, I used `iT` as the integer loop counter, and then used it directly in the formula.  This produced a piecewise graph for `iT` > `ic8t`.  When I added `i` as the counter, and converted `iT` to real before using it in the formula, the graph came out smooth as it should.  Why should it matter whether `iT` is real or integer when plugging in to the formula?  My compiler is g77.

EDIT:  The formula gives some inaccurate values for `iT` < `ic8t` as well.

Comment: It looks like you ran into an issue with an implicit type conversion - something was cast into an integer where it should have been real.  I tried a few simple cases with my copy of g77 to see if I could reproduce this and was unable to - trying the sample code above wouldn't compile since my copy of g77 didn't like the fortran 90 constructs.

Comment: How is your g77 able to compile a Fortran 90 code? Isn't g77 just a symlink to some different compiler on your system?

Comment: @Vladimir, I am using the 'Force' program which I believe uses g77 on the back end.  It seems that the compiler supports some Fortran 90 features but not others, which is consistent with the g77 webpage documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just use INTEGER variable `i` (as you mentioned in your comment) you probably have arithmetic overflow. You can either convert `i` to REAL as you did or [choose an appropriate kind parameter](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/selected_int_kind) for it. A small example:

```
PROGRAM ex

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: long = selected_int_kind(10)

! Here we have arithmetic overflow  
! PRINT *, 2000**3
! But not here
  PRINT *, 2000_long**3

END PROGRAM ex
```

Comment: the version of the program that I posted is the working version.  What I am trying to find is the spot where the program doesn't work if `i` is used in the formula instead of `iT`.

Comment: Than you probably have an arithmetic overflow when rising some thousands to the power more than 2, i.e. when i will be 2000 the attempt to calculate 2000**3 will cause arithmetic overflow. So you basically calculate wrong numbers. You can use selected_int_kind() intrinsic function to choose appropriate kind parameter for your INTEGER variable i or just make it REAL as you did.

Comment: Thanks! I used a larger integer type and it fixed the problem.